# SSH tunneling and Gstreamer

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, ssh-tunnel

Is this a gstreamer issue or ssh tunnel problem?

I'm trying to tunnel Gstreamer over ssh. Doing this on the local client works (plays the video to the waiting gstreamer client on the local client):

```
ssh -f -L 5001:127.0.0.1:5000 remoteuser@remoteip raspivid -n -w 1280 -h 720 -b 4500000   -fps 10 -vf -hf -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc !  h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001
```

But when I execute this on the local client:

```
ssh -f -L 5001:127.0.0.1:5000 remoteuser@remoteip -N
```

and ssh in to the remote and do the same command it doesn't play?